# QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' is not defined (when executing QGIS Plugin)

Tags: qgis

I like to extract a buffer of a railway system to a .poly file and use this one to extract further object within this buffer from an OSM file of germany.

I have defined a CRS for the layer of interest (UTM 32N)

[image]

The message `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' is not defined` is displayed when I try to use the plugin osmpoly in QGIS.

[image]

how to fix this?

I tried both suggestions. Did not work. neither the combination of them. New messages are displayed for

suggestion 1)

[image]

suggestion 2)

[image]

sugestion 1) and 2) combined (do not know if this makes sense at all)

[image]

after suggestion 1) and change linie 166 as below:

[image]

When I export my layer out of the used geopackage to .shp in WGS 84 (4326), the failure messages do not show anymore but the .poly is not created either.

Comment: So yeah - maybe a layer has no CRS definition? As far as we don't have a screenshot or further information, any answer would be just guesswork.

Comment: Can you share the data? Can you describe a bit more detailed your workflow, how you produced the polygon?

Comment: Can you describe how the plugin should work? Can't find a documentation and when I run it, I get the error `No string field names, Exiting`, aborting the process.

Comment: the plugin is supposed to transform the polygon (of the buffer) to a .poly file. from there I like to extract OSM data within this polygon. I expected to select the buffer then run the plugin but then this failure message is displayed. I am struggeling with other ways to get that .poly file so that's why I tried within QGIS itself.

Comment: With `from qgis.core import *` uncommented, as per Szym's answer, change line 166 in `polygenerator.py` file from `transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)` to `transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance())`. That should fix the 2nd error. However, it may be a case of fix one error and find another one until all problems are fixed.

Comment: this is excatly what happens. failure message is above in the question

Comment: @BenW I can confirm that in my case your advice was enough (no more issues).

Comment: @BAE_23 We're close to solving. Please restart QGIS and try again. Your last screenshot suggest that still neither solution 1 nor 2 is applied.

Comment: I tried with WGS 84 and a shape file instead of geopackage. unistalled the plug-in and reinstalled it. works just fine. .poly file is created. can not tell the quality of this file but at least the file is created. is the geopackage the problem by any chance?

Comment: @BAE_23 Also a possible workaround: create a layer in WGS 1984 CRS (4326) and vectorize your polygon (or mutlipolygon) in this feature. Then you'd avoid CRS Transformation (I did it and that's why yesterday I didn't have Error message. Today I realized that you use CRS 25832 and I can see your trouble)

Comment: I replaced the file with the one containing your advices. still works fine with WGS 84. .poly file is created. Why is UTM 32 N / 25832 a problem ?

Comment: @BAE_23 I'm glad that shapefile with WGS 84 worked. I'm pretty sure that gpgk layer in WGS 84 also should work (pls see my comment above). I'm also convinced that if you apply my solution and comment from Ben W also other coordinate systems should be ok (they work for me). If you still have time pls test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138687/discussion-between-szym-and-bae-23).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WGS 84 (4326) works for me (as .shp and geopackage). unfortunately the .poly file is too big for OSMCONVERT but might be still functional with OSMOSIS or other programms.

Comment: tried without dissolving the buffer, still no able to process with OSMFILTER

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is a bug in the code. Error message *QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem is not defined* is related to plug-in Python code rather than to lack of CRS defined in your layer. Now there are two options - you could obviously contact developer or you can try to fix the code yourself. If you choose the latter, go to the file C:/Users/User.../osmpoly_export/polygenerator.py (full path as in you screenshot), open it in text (or Python) editor and uncomment line 32 i.e. remove hash in the line:

`#from qgis.core import *`

or alternatively (and more pythonic) add in from section:

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateTransform
from qgis.core import QgsProject
```

Another required change is to the line in the code (look for it around line 170):
Replace:

```
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)
```

With:

```
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance())
```

After that reload the plug-in (or restart QGIS)

Comment: Corrected answer using hint by Ben W (thanks). Workaround to the issue is to have your polygon data in WGS1984 - then no coordinate transformation is needed and hopefully plug-in will not crash

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use something without having imported it. The [NameError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) tells you that there is nothing known as "`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`".

Add this to your imports at the top of your file:

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
```

Afterwards the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` is available to be referenced and used in your code.

Comment: Didn't notice your answer until I wrote mine. Remark: in the code of polygenerator.py (pls note that this is plug-in code, not written by asking person) there is at least one more reference to qgis.core, that is why I suggested in my answer to uncomment line with #from qgis.core import * (yes I know it is not really pythonic). What is weird is that for me plug-in worked without change to this line although it needed some other references.

Comment: did the plugin give you the .poly file? what will happen after you chose and polygon and click on that plugin? @Szym

Comment: Yes, .poly files were successfully created. But there were some troubles. In my case it required input layer to contain mutlipolygons rather than polygons. And of course there must be at least one attribute field of String type.  After I click on plug-in icon window asking to select one of the String type fields appeared.

Comment: @Szym this window appears for me too but then the above mentioned failure messages appear.  I've tried few other things (creating new string field, other computer) nothing works.